Is it possible to write a sinusoidal steady state response of a RC circuit with diode involved?

Let's consider this circuit. When everything is ideal and the forward voltage of the diode is 0. When the current is going forward, the time constant is R1*C. When reversed, it is (R1//R2)*C. Is it possible to write the response of vC without too complicated math?

why are you asking a question that has a yes/no answer?  ... what use is a yes answer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What's complicated for me may be a piece of cake for you. But this is a non-linear circuit, so do not expect anything as simple as the phasor calculus for linear circuits.
Assume at some unknown moment of time there's a certain voltage Ux in the capacitor and at the same time the sinusoidal source voltage is just growing upwards and reaches that same voltage.The diode starts to conduct and stays conductive as long as the capacitor voltage is less than the sinusoidal source voltage.
The sinusoidal source voltage finally drops below the capacitor voltage and the diode stops conducting. But the capacitor has got some charge, its voltage is more than Ux.
The capacitor voltage decreases gradually due discharging through R2 as long as the sinusoidal source voltage is less than the capacitor voltage. At some point the tide turns and the sinusoidal source voltage grows again and meets the new capacitor voltage Uy.
You can probably solve when the capacitor is charged and when it's discharged and get some equation for Ux and Uy.
Solve the steady state case by writing Uy = Ux and the length of the full charge discharge cycle is just as long as the period of the sinusoidal source voltage.
Working through this with symbolical equations is too much for me, but good luck for you with the cake. I cannot guarantee the solution can be written with any expression containing only elementary functions.
Circuit analyzer programs (including the CircuitLab given here for us) solve any numerical case in seconds.
